# How to restrict access privilege between two classes in java?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, access-modifiers, design-principles

I have two classes `Player` and `Game`

```java
public class Player {
    private List<String> cards;

    public Player(){
        cards = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
```

```java
public class Game {
    List<Player> players;

    public Game(List<Player> players){
        this.players = new ArrayList<Player>();

        for(Player player: players){
            this.players.add(player);
        }

    }

    private void distributeCards(){
        ...

    }

    public void start(){
        distributeCards()
        ...

    }

}
```

the `distributeCards` method of `Game` class needs to modify the cards attribute of a Player object. If I declare a public or protected method in the Player class for that, other classes in the same package will have the privilege as well but I don't want that. In this situation what can I do?

Let me know if I'm breaking any rules of design principles or design patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things I would consider, given the assumption that the `Player` must expose the list of cards somehow:

- Maybe, in your design & implementation, the cards are not a property of the player but of the game; e.g.:

  ```
    public class Game {
        List<Player> players;
        Map<Player, List<String>> cards;
  ```

  This would work if only the `Game` wants to know the list of cards or if the rest of the system can ask the `Game` for the list of cards of a specific `Player`.
- Maybe the `Game` is responsible for providing the `Player` objects, so it has access to its internal state. `Player` could be an interface that `Game` is responsible for providing with a private inner class. Or `Player` is an immutable class, constructed by the `Game` with a list of cards.

  Another way to approach this option is to think e.g. that a "Player" is actually a user within a game. So the `Game` takes the list of users that will be playing and transforms it to a list of `Player` objects. The `Game` is responsible for the list of cards in the `Player` object.
- A `giveCard(Card)` method just like Code-Apprentice writes. This means that you rethink your constraints and allow everyone to modify the `Player`. Additionally you can even make a convenience method `giveCards(List<Card>)` where the `Player` **copies** the card list argument in its internal state. This way no outsider is able to directly modify the `Player`'s internal state.

  As an amendment to this option, you could add validation logic to the `giveCards(List<Card>)` method, so that e.g. it throws an `IllegalStateException` if the `Player` already has cards. The drawback here is that this behavior is not obvious from the design of the class.
- You could move the logic of card distribution to the `Player`. So, e.g. the `Game` shuffles the cards and gives the shuffled list to the first `Player`; the `Player` picks some cards, moves them to its internal state and removes them from the shuffled list; `Game` gives the remaining cards to the next `Player`. This is not always appropriate, you judge according to your design.
- In my own experiments with card games the design was that `Game`, `Player`, `Card`, `Hand` (the list of cards of a `Player`) etc are immutable value objects holding the current state of a game. (Hint: check out [Immutables](https://immutables.github.io/).) Another class, say `GameEngine`, is responsible for taking a state and returning a *new* immutable state in response to a user or game action. `Game` is the root state object, everything else is reachable through it. E.g.:

  ```
    public class GameEngine {
        public Game distributeCards(Game game) {
            ...
        }
    }
  ```

  You can add the business logic methods to the `Game` class if you want, the gist here is the immutability and that each action returns a new state. Think Redux for Java :)

Answer (score 1):

> the distributeCards method of Game class needs to modify the cards attribute of a Player object.

One class should never modify the attributes of another class. This breaks the encapsulation principle.

Instead, the `Player` object should declare a `public` method which the `Game` object can call. For example, you might add `public giveCard(Card card)` to the `Player` class to simulate handing a single card to a player. Then the `Player` class decides what to do with the `Card` object. For example, it could insert it into the `cards` list.

Note that in this interaction, the `Game` object has no knowledge of the `cards` list. It only knows that `Player` has a method named `giveCard()` which it can call.